# Install ubuntu problem and grub rescue error

Tags: grub2, system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu via a bootable pendrive, it is showing the error:

```
The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition#2 (sda) at /boot/efi failed.
```

After the installation when I boot up, it is going into a grub rescue screen.

How can I debug/fix this?

Updated output

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA HGST HTS545025A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   ext4            EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   248GB  248GB   ext4
 3      248GB   250GB  1579MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Sony Storage Media (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3931MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      28.7kB  3931MB  3931MB  primary  fat32        boot
```

New update for the Command sudo parted -l

```
pc@pc-HP-241-G1:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA HGST HTS545025A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  2000MB  1999MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)  boot
 2      2001MB  250GB   248GB   extended
 5      2001MB  2200MB  199MB   logical   ext4
 6      2201MB  108GB   106GB   logical   ext4
 7      108GB   250GB   142GB   logical   ext4
```

Update for the Command sudo blkid /dev/sda1

```
pc@pc-HP-241-G1:~$ sudo blkid /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for pc: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="40678a83-42f4-4863-8b4b-ebafce9ab0db" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="e79cf3e7-01"
```

update based on this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu)

```
pc@pc-HP-241-G1:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA HGST HTS545025A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      525MB   2648MB  2122MB  linux-swap(v1)
 3      2648MB  97.0GB  94.4GB  ext4
 4      97.0GB  250GB   153GB   ext4

pc@pc-HP-241-G1:~$ sudo blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="452D-30A6" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0ad2ab73-0046-4265-a5cd-a7536e08e51f"
```

Comment: Have you disabled secure boot?

Comment: Boot up into your live Ubuntu UFD. Then open Terminal and run command `sudo parted -l`. Edit your question with the results posted there.

Comment: yes, the secured bot is disabled @Denny,  The Question has been edited paul Benson,,, Thank you for helping

Comment: From your booted UFD, type command `sudo blkid /dev/sda1`, and again print result.

Comment: I installed the Ubuntu OS by making a new partition table by selecting something else and created my own partitions such as the new update in the question..

Now my problem is to partition and increase the size of /boot partition that i created and another one is that when i plug a Bootable windows usb it throws an error..

Thanks for the help after reading your replies i am getting some idea.

Comment: You cannot have an ESP as ext4 for UEFI boot as shown in first list. You then converted to BIOS with MBR partitioning and have made swap as boot? That may just be boot flag which grub does not use, so is not main issue.  I would suggest just totally reinstall in UEFI boot mode as let installer set partitions. It will default to ESP (FAT32) and / (root) as ext4. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: i re installed the Ubuntu based on the link that you shared. See updated Question

Comment: Sometimes it's better not to use links but take advice given to you on the page. As you didn't get back to me I couldn't advise you, but oldfred has since shown you that on the original printout (parted -l) there was an error on the esp boot format which could have been easily corrected. As it is you've converted from UEFI back to legacy BIOS which was unnecessary and pointless.

Comment: @Paul Benson i know that i have corrupted the whole grub boot thing... Thank you for the advice will remember this one.